# Select divs separate, with same id

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to select divs that are with same name, but to select them separate ?

```
<div id='wholestuff'>
<div id='item'>
info something
</div>
<div id='item'>
info something
</div>
<div id='item'>
else
</div>
<div id='item'>
stuff
</div>
<div id='item'>
info something
</div>
<div id='item'>
info something
</div>
</div>
```

And i want to select the second div with id item .. how to do that ?

Comment: An `id` should be unique per page; one id for one element.

Comment: As noted id's should be unique . However if you want to select div's with the same name as mentioned in the title , you can use document.getElementsByName('item') to get an array of elements

Comment: This is akin to all the users in your site having the same username. A class would would be more suitable here.

Comment: I have an output from database that outputs in an one id, so becouse of thati need id

Comment: Besides the "id" problem, you have this question tagged javascript *and* CSS, but never mentioned which language you're trying to select the div with. (And to others, there is no mention of jQuery here, so why the jQuery answers?)

Comment: The jQuery answers may not be pure Javascript, but they happen to use correct CSS3 selectors, so get off my back good sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not advisable to give different elements the same id. Id's have to be unique. You are grouping your 'items' within div#wholestuff, so if you want the second element, that would be:

```
document.getElementById('wholestuff').getElementsByTagName('div')[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is not to use the same ID for more than one element on the page - it must be unique.  Use unique IDs and then it will be easy to select the element you want.

Using the same ID for multiple elements is not compliant, and can cause unpredictable behavior in different browsers.

Comment: Yeah but in this case a list or classes or more suited than IDs

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your can use a list in that case

```
<ul id='wholestuff'>
  <li>
    info something
  </li>
  <li>
    info something
  </li>
  <li>
    info something
  </li>
  <li>
    info something
  </li>

</ul>
```

And there's a nth-child selector in css too. To select the third one your need:

```
#wholestuff li:nth-child(3) {  }
```

Answer (score -1):

jQuery does it like:

```
$('#item:eq(2)')
```

But you really shouldn't have multiple DIVs with identical IDs. You should use class names instead. IDs should always be unique

Comment: What the hell? I get a negative vote for a correct answer, merely because I used jQuery? (which he should be using in the first place unless he works at Google and can't afford the overhead)

Comment: Would a Mootools or Prototype answer have been appropriate? Just because jQuery is popular doesn't literally mean everyone is using it. The jQuery answers to non-jQuery tagged/related questions is a bad habit, if you know he's using jQuery - it's a good answer. If you had put it in CSS3 context instead, it wouldn't have attracted my downvote. For the record, it's nothing personal - no need to get upset. I love jQuery too.

Comment: @Wesley: yes, they would be appropriate since each of those frameworks are supersets of Javascript. They would not have qualified for the "Correct Answer" badge since the OP asked for raw JS, but they would certainly be helpful additions to the page. I know the question wasn't tagged with jQuery, but it's likely that someone searching for a frameworked answer to the exact same question might wind up on this page looking for an answer.